# How to send SMS automatically in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send sms to a particular phone number in my flutter application. I tried all flutter packages regarding this issue and github repos but I screw up and did not find any useful source.

Here's my last attempt code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(new MaterialApp(
title: "Send sms Demo",
home: new SendSms(),
 ));
 }


   class SendSms extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SendSmsState createState() => new _SendSmsState();
 }

    class _SendSmsState extends State<SendSms> {
    Future<Null> sendSms()async {
SmsSender smsSender = new SmsSender();
smsSender.sendSms(new SmsMessage('+*****7337544', 'test send sms')); //instead xxx... to receiver 
 phone
 }

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new Material(
  child: new Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: new FlatButton(onPressed: () => sendSms(), child: const Text("Click here to Send SMS")),
  ),
);
}
}
```

And I put this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I’ve recently uploaded a sample project on Github that make use of the [telephony](https://pub.dev/packages/telephony) package, which request for SEND_SMS permissions and dispatch SMS.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/rodrigoc85/flutter-sms-dispatcher)

In this sample you have to fire the message with a button, but you can do it automatically if you want to.